# Accessing data from other website to know if the client has paid or unpaid status after logging in

Tags: php, javascript

We have been developing a web application, and we have utilized login system of this site http://www.cura2apptrade.herobo.com/index.php/ , this is my site I have uploaded to a free web hosting company. We have just embedded its login system to another website which we are currently working on. The site indicated above is where the registration of the clients happens, the other site that we are working is where the client will log in. It works fine, however only the email and the password that we can access.

What we want is to access the status of the client logging in in the website if he/she has a paid/unpaid status, paid status if the client has already paid the subscription, unpaid otherwise. But we don't yet get the right approach to get that information from a separated site. We have been trying to apply API but just don't get it right. I have read some to use JSONP but I do not how to use it right. Can anyone help us with this problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {

        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://www.cura2apptrade.herobo.com/bb-admin.php/invoice?status=unpaid?jsonp=?',
          dataType: "jsonp",
          jsonp: "callback",
          success: function(data)
          {
            $('#main').html(data);
          }
        });

    }); 

</script>
```

Comment: This question is very broad. We have no idea what you've tried, so short of writing an API for you, all we can do is point you to tutorials from [Google](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=how+to+create+an+api+php&oq=how+to+create+an+api+php&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i22l3.3020.3378.1.3597.4.4.0.0.0.0.140.381.2j2.4.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.8rjbngblNjU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=4557a2d1dccec43c&bpcl=38625945&biw=1235&bih=683). You said you've been trying, so _what_ have you tried? Got any example code? What part isn't working? Help us to help you.

Comment: Also, if you can access a password through an API, you've done something _very_ wrong. Read this article: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Comment: http://www.cura2apptrade.herobo.com/index.php/, in this site,we will put our system to sell it through subscription,..Now we want to access the status of the clients who made a subscription for our system if he/she is paid or unpaid..since we dont have access to this site database,,is it possible to retrieve clients details from this site to our site..what approach we need to take..?

Comment: Can you put any code on the site with the subscription info? If so, you could make a soap call (or similar) to get subscription status. Said call could be encrypted too.

Comment: yes..we can put code but it is in the login system code only that we can put some changes of the code..

Comment: i just found out now that i have access to the database..i am able to visit the database invoice table with the lists of clients there,,however the database is placed in web host server http://sql16.000webhost.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php?db=a1131474_boxbil&lang=en-utf-8&convcharset=iso-8859-1&collation_connection=utf8_unicode_ci&token=f78a24d7099076beffc016061cae1c32&phpMyAdmin=iHEjDJbpcdnGsIb5HKd4o7XWSfe..how can i access the database to my website?

Comment: Ofcourse. You have to provide hostname,username and password.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [oAuth](http://oauth.net/2/) for handling client/server interaction. It's definitely a lot safer than sending passwords over to the main site like you're doing.

I didn't quite grasp if the the paid/unpaid information is located client or server side. If it's client side I imagine you should be able to send that through a get variable in the URL or something similar and validate it server side (along with the oAuth authentication).